# How can i place an image as background for some html elements( images, text, headings, inputboxes, links)

Tags: html, css

These other elements should appear on the inserted image.

The backdround color is set then i want a white box in center and all contents on the white box.

like this page.

I am just practicing not creating any page for phishing.

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can find some info at [W3Cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

However, with CSS you are able to change almost all of an element html property.

For example, if you have a header element as:

```
<h1>Header with Background</h1>
```

you can set a background image with css:

```
<style>
h1 {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
</style>
```

I leave an example in which the image of the background of different HTML tags is applied

```css
.bg {
    background-image:   url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/Color_icon_red.svg/1024px-Color_icon_red.svg.png");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1 class="bg">Hello World!</h1>

<p>This page has an image as the background!</p>

<p class="bg">CIAO!</p>
<span class="bg">HELLO!</span>
<button class="bg">HOLA!</button>

</body>
</html>
```